# error in the programme - inheritance

Tags: inheritance, subclass, super

I have a have a java code that it is seems to be error in there ; I suggested that the constructor which is in the B class is undefined in the super class , and the method Circle (radius) is undefined in the B class.

```
public class Circle {
    private double redius;

    public Circle (double radius)
    {
        radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRedius() {
        return redius;
    }

    /*public void setRedius(double redius) {
        this.redius = redius;
    }*/

    public double getArea(double radius)
    {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
     class B extends Circle{
         private double length;

         B(double radius , double length)//this constructor is undefined in the super class
         {
             Circle (radius);// this method is undefined 
             length = length;
         }

         public double getArea()
         {
             return getArea() * length;
         }
     }
```

Comment: You need to check your spelling throughout, redius != radius...

Answer (score 0):

Use `super(radius);` rather than `Circle(radius);`.

Also,  the assignment `length = length` does nothing at all. Use `this.length = length;` to assign the `length` argument to the `length` instance field. (There's a similar problem in the `Circle` constructor - it should be `redius = radius;` (careful of your slightly different spelling), which works because the parameter and instance field have different names, removing the necessity of specifying which one you're talking about. The Java compiler is not clairvoyant.)